# MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 NodeJS mongoose express local database

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, localhost

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017

DB_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb"
```

---

```
MongooseServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017 at 
NativeConnection.Connection.openUri 
(C:\\Users\\ivan\\Desktop\\NodeJS\\notes- 
app\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\connection.js:797:32) at 
C:\\Users\\ivan\\Desktop\\NodeJS\\notes- 
app\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\index.js:330:10 at 
C:\\Users\\ivan\\Desktop\\NodeJS\\notes- 
app\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\helpers\\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5 at 
new Promise () at promiseOrCallback 
(C:\\Users\\ivan\\Desktop\\NodeJS\\notes- 
app\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\helpers\\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10) 
at Mongoose.\_promiseOrCallback 
(C:\\Users\\ivan\\Desktop\\NodeJS\\notes- 
app\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\index.js:1151:10) at Mongoose.connect 
(C:\\Users\\ivan\\Desktop\\NodeJS\\notes- 
app\\node_modules\\mongoose\\lib\\index.js:329:20) at Object. 
(C:\\Users\\ivan\\Desktop\\NodeJS\\notes-app\\src\\db.js:3:10)
at Module.\_compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14) at 
Object.Module.\_extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147:10) {
reason: TopologyDescription 
        { type: 'Unknown', servers: Map(1) 
        { 'localhost:27017' =\> \[ServerDescription\] },
           stale: false, compatible: true, 
           eartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000, localThresholdMS: 15, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined 
        }}
```

Answer:

```
DB_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/testdb"

replace localhost to 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Hi, put the final solution in a real answer, not editing the question. Take a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you!